# Where may I find the IObservable<T>.ToTask extension method?

Tags: system.reactive

I have Rx in two places:

1. v2.2.5 of the binary distribution I got via NuGet
2. The latest code base from github in which the `AssemblyVersion` attribute reads 2.2.0.0.

In neither of these can I find the `ToTask` method. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229587(v=vs.103).aspx) reports its presence in the `System.Reactive.dll` assembly in the `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks` namespace, neither of which exist in either of my downloads listed above. I am assuming things have gotten moved since that MSDN article was published?

Where may I find the method? Has it been renamed since?

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you. That is reportedly a namespace? I checked but none of my assemblies have that namespace, and neither does the source.

Comment: It's in `System.Reactive.Linq.dll` under the `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks` namespace.

Comment: Thank you. Please put that down as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `System.Reactive.Linq.dll` under the `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks` namespace.